# Details of .NET Remoting System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException (Connection Refused)

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

Does anyone know what causes a .NET remoting server to throw a `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Connection refused` exception?

An example stack trace from the exception can be seen immediately below.  In this example, the exception is thrown when attempting to get the value of a remote object property after having successfully setup a `TcpChannel` and having creating a well known object proxy via `Activator.GetObject()`.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Connection refused

Server stack trace: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.HostConnectionPool.CreateConnection () [0x0002f] in <13447c6f047f47b8b8744bf3fc9e97d0>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.HostConnectionPool.GetConnection () [0x0009d] in <13447c6f047f47b8b8744bf3fc9e97d0>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpConnectionPool.GetConnection (System.String host, System.Int32 port) [0x00057] in <13447c6f047f47b8b8744bf3fc9e97d0>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, System.IO.Stream requestStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, System.IO.Stream& responseStream) [0x00022] in <13447c6f047f47b8b8744bf3fc9e97d0>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg) [0x00066] in <13447c6f047f47b8b8744bf3fc9e97d0>:0 
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke (System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy rp, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg, System.Exception& exc, System.Object[]& out_args) [0x0014d] in <e50d21fbfba24408b2ca69b0d707999a>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_remoting_wrapper(intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke) AtComm.IAtState.get_RegisteredClients()
  at AtComm.AtClient.GetConfig () [0x00000] in <8aa350cf21d7487a888de25463df9ca3>:0 
  at AtComm.AtClient..ctor () [0x0001d] in <8aa350cf21d7487a888de25463df9ca3>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Connection refused
```

At current, I'm not asking for assistance regarding the issue I am facing.  Rather, I would like to know if anyone can provide any details on what causes this exception to be raised generally.

I can't find any details about this exception within Microsoft's documentation, nor from searches of the web, other than the very high level documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.remotingexception?view=netframework-4.8

Any detail anyone could give on this exception would be much appreciated, as without this information I am not sure how to proceed in debugging the real issue at hand.

Comment: Perhaps the server isn't running? Or refused the connection due to authentication? Wrong port or IP? Windows Firewall blocking the port? Why are you using such an ancient technology anyway? Ancient as in replaced-by-WCF 12 years ago ancient

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The server is running and it is operable from other clients using the underlying same code (the client interface is a lib).  Moreover, these client applications can operate from the same host which the troublesome client software is experiencing this particular exception.  Port and IP information are both good.  I don't get to make the call regarding the technology, as we're interfacing new client software with an existing application and timescales don't currently permit this interface to be changed.  If it were up to me, this interface would be replaced.

Comment: The server application is being reached by the client, but the server is rejecting the connection for some reason not known to me.